# What are common culture temperatures?

Tags: cell-culture, temperature, medium

In literature, authors sometimes refer to 37°C as a common culturing temperature. As I understand it, those are temperatures that are conventionally used for incubators in laboratories. For mesophilic bacteria, I found that common culturing temperatures are 28, 30 and 37°C. However, I was wondering whether that can be translated to Archaea, Fungi and/or algae research. What are the temperatures that people typically use in the laboratory to investigate mesophiles from these taxa?